# React Redux - Can't pass the string via dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to dispatch a action with String , but the `payload` / `tabName` still showing `null` in the `console.log` in the reducer, can anyone help? Thank you.

**Dispatch**

```
store.dispatch(getDetail("new string"));
```

**MapDispatchToProps**

```
function MapDispatchToPropsTab(state) {   
    return {  
        getDetail : (tabName) => dispatch(getDetail(tabName)),
    }  
}  

function getDetail(tabName) {
      return {
          type: 'GET_DETAIL',
          payload:tabName
      }
    }
```

**Reducer**

```
function reducreForTabs(state = initialState4, action) {
      if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0
      }

      switch(action.type) {
          case 'GET_DETAIL': {

              console.log(action.payload);

              var tabs2 = {'title': action.payload};

              return {
                    ...state,
                    tabs: state.tabs.concat(tabs2)
                  };

          }
          default :{
              return state
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should have it in `action.payload`, not `action.tabName`

Comment: YES , i edited my question , both doesnt work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo.

```
function MapDispatchToPropsTab(dispatch) {   // not state
    return {  
        getDetail : (tabName) => dispatch(getDetail(tabName)),
    }  
}
```